# Web scraping when paths_allowed = FALSE

Tags: r, rvest

I am attempting to use rvest to scrape data from a public health website. When I checked whether the site could be scraped:

```
robotstxt::paths_allowed('https://cityofcambridge.shinyapps.io/COVID19/')
```

returned FALSE. It would make my colleague's daily copy/paste steps much less error-prone and less of a drudgery if I could get her the data she needs in R. Unfortunately, some of the daily data she needs is not retrievable from the site after the day is past.

Is there a way of getting around the web scraping restriction? This is a public health website with a stated purpose of providing data to the public, run by the city of Cambridge public health department. I don't see an ethical concern here, but perhaps I am not understanding this.

I am somewhat experienced in R, especially the tidyverse, and new to web scraping. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `robots.txt` is really intended for web crawlers rather than end-users. Whether you are allowed to scrape the data is down to the terms & conditions of the website. However, the site itself points to an [open data portal](https://data.cambridgema.gov/dataset/COVID-19-Cases-in-Cambridge-Daily-Snapshot/5dms-3pz8/data) where the data can be downloaded in one big gulp as a csv. It is also updated daily, and seems to be added to cumulatively.

Comment: Sorry I could not get back to you until now. Sadly, the open data portal does not include community case counts by race, though this is featured prominently in the website tables that are not downloadable. Not sure why these were omitted from the open data portal, since the other demographics, age and gender, are present there.
In R, the robotstxt package is used to "check if bots (spiders, crawler, scrapers, …) are allowed to access specific resources on a domain." see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/robotstxt/versions/0.7.13

Comment: This is a correction to my previous comment. Some open data datasets here include race, even though it is not included in the description. I should have checked the actual contents to be sure. They are accessible via API so this problem is solved. I am marking Allan Cameron's comment as the solution since it put me on the right track.